# XP, how can I copy permissions from one partition to another, had no permssions and getting access denied trying to fix?

Tags: windows-xp, security, permissions

For some reason, I'm not sure why, I have no permissions in the security tab/advanced tab for one partition. I'm trying to add them back by copying them manually from another partition.

However when I try to replace permissions entries on some files it says access denied, then I have to click continue.

I haven't much clue what this is all about, but I'd like to fix this as some folders in my partition aren't accessible in shares from other machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sign in as an administrator, browse to the root of the partition, on each folder in there you will have to right click and select properties, browse to the security tab, click advanced on the bottom. While in the advanced settings browse to the owner tab, select your account from the list and tick the check box to apply to sub folders. It will look like this:

[image]

Comment: sorry for the delaym then what ?

Comment: @jules then what? Hit okay and it will replace the owner on all sub directories allowing you to fix the access denied issue.